# ¿Como determinar si los valores de una lista con 0's y 1's son consecutivos?

Tags: python

Por ejemplo: Recibimos una lista `l` con los siguientes valores

```
l =[1,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,1]
```

Ahora quiero saber cuantos grupos de 1's y 0's hay en la lista, agrupandolos de la siguiente forma `{111}{00}{11}{0}{1}`

Ya he intentado comparar el valor actual de `l[x]` y el valor de `l[x+1]` pero me marca el error del indice fuera de rango.

Comment: te lo marca al llegar al ultimo.. pero seria mucho mas facil ayudarte si vieramos tu codigo.. asi, como esta, no sabemos como ayudarte a corregir tu codigo porque no lo vemos...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Python trae una excelente biblioteca con funciones de utilidad, en la que muchas veces encontrarás justo lo que necesitas.

El problema que planteas lo resuelve la función `groupby()` del módulo `itertools`. Esta función itera por el iterable que le pases (en tu caso la lista `l`) y te va devolviendo parejas `(valor, grupo)` en la que `valor` es el elemento que se repite dentro del grupo, y `grupo` es otro iterable con los elementos de ese grupo.

Puede sonar un poco confuso, pero el siguiente ejemplo te ayudará a entenderlo:

```
from  itertools import groupby

l =[1,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,1]

for digito, grupo in groupby(l):
  # Cada iteración de este bucle nos devuelve un grupo de tu secuencia
  print(digito, "-->", list(grupo))
```

Esto imprimirá:

```
1 --> [1, 1, 1]
0 --> [0, 0]
1 --> [1, 1]
0 --> [0]
1 --> [1]
```

En tu caso el valor de `digito` realmente no lo quieres, y puedes quedarte únicamente con los valores de `grupo`.

Usando una *comprensión de listas* lo que buscas se reduce a una línea:

```
resultado = [list(g) for k,g in groupby(l)]
```

En este caso el resultado sería:

```
[[1, 1, 1], [0, 0], [1, 1], [0], [1]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Una solución:

```
lista = str([1,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,1])[1:-1].replace(", ", "").replace("10", "1^0").replace("01", "0^1").split("^")
```

donde

```
str([1,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,1])
```

convierte la lista en una cadena

```
'[1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1]'
```

a la cual le sacamos el primer y último caracter:

```
str([1,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,1])[1:-1]
```

dejando

```
'1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1'
```

Los siguiente `replace` eliminan las `", "` e insertan un `"^"` entre cada 0 y 1:

```
str([1,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,1])[1:-1].replace(", ", "").replace("10", "1^0").replace("01", "0^1")
```

lo que deja esta cadena:

```
'111^00^11^0^1'
```

que ahora podemos dividir usando `split("^")`, con lo que se obtiene

```
['111', '00', '11', '0', '1']
```